# React Render <strong>{this.state.exampleState} </strong> not applying strong weighting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently have a react render function similar to as follows

```
render() {
  return (
   <div>
     <div className="alert alert-success" role="alert"> Well done! You have added <strong>{this.state.exampleState}</strong> to your team</div>
   </div>
  );
}
```

The `<strong></strong>` tags seem to have no effect on text held by {this.state.exampleState} despite rendering the in the `<strong></strong>` html tags in the DOM.

This seems to be a more subtle aspect of JSX that ive yet to come across. May be simple. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: check your css settings on <strong>

Comment: +1 @dandavis I doubt it is the css or may be some browser extension. React has nothing to do with appearance.

Comment: @dandavis tested <strong> on rendering plain text and it has no problem with 'bolding' text. only seems to present issues when rendering variables (in this case this.state.exampleState) enclosed in '{ }'

Comment: if the tag is in the DOM, i don't see why CSS would not affect it, no matter what framework populated it...

Comment: It's working for me with plain text and variables, the issue should be in your css. Remove the css and see if it works without it.

Comment: Also, sharing a jsfiddle would probably help

Comment: What is initial value given to this.state.exampleState? I doubt it is not initialized.

Comment: I realize this is a bit old, but in case anyone else stumbles accross it, I had a similar problem and the cause ended up being the `normalize.css` package. Totally didn't expect it to do away with bold font weight for `<strong>` tags...